# Resuming tasks: Unable to update graph with root task *XXXX* since that root task is not suspended

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-task

I am trying to build some tasks to automate some of my processes. I have included the code for my tasks which execute successfully and have tested out manually, it achieves the correct end result. Also, please forgive my lack of SQL etiquette, just started working on DB's and really learning SQL about a month ago.

Here are the resume commands for the tasks. The first one works fine, the other three however do not.

```
alter task create_hubspot_mql_yesterday_table resume;
alter task create_pega_mql_yesterday_table resume;
alter task create_hubspot_pega_diff_yesterday_table resume;
alter task suspendwarehouse3 resume;
```

The error I am getting is this:
**Unable to update graph with root task *XXXX* since that root task is not suspended.**

```
-- task 1: creates the hubspot mql yesterday report from hubspot data
create or replace task create_hubspot_mql_yesterday_table
    warehouse = pc_fivetran_wh
    schedule = 'USING CRON 0 6-20 * * MON-FRI America/Denver'
  as create or replace table myfirstdatabase.hubspot.hubspot_mql_yesterday
  as select * from pc_fivetran_db.hubspot.contact where PROPERTY_HS_LIFECYCLESTAGE_MARKETINGQUALIFIEDLEAD_DATE < current_date 
    and PROPERTY_HS_LIFECYCLESTAGE_MARKETINGQUALIFIEDLEAD_DATE > current_date - INTERVAL '1 d';

-- task 2: creates the pega mql yesterday report from pega lead data
create or replace task create_pega_mql_yesterday_table
    warehouse = pc_fivetran_wh
    after create_hubspot_mql_yesterday_table
  as create or replace table myfirstdatabase.hubspot.pega_mql_yesterday
  as select * from myfirstdatabase.public.pega_leads where BECAMEAMQLDATE <= current_date + INTERVAL '7 h'
    and BECAMEAMQLDATE >= current_date - INTERVAL '1 d';

-- task 3: full outer join to determine differnce in id's between hubspot and pega tables
create or replace task create_hubspot_pega_diff_yesterday_table
    warehouse = pc_fivetran_wh
    after create_pega_mql_yesterday_table
  as create or replace table myfirstdatabase.hubspot.hubspot_pega_mql_yesterday_delta
  as select 
        myfirstdatabase.hubspot.hubspot_mql_yesterday.id as hubspot_contact_id,
        myfirstdatabase.hubspot.pega_mql_yesterday.hubspotcontactid as pega_hubspot_contact_id
    from myfirstdatabase.hubspot.hubspot_mql_yesterday
    full outer join myfirstdatabase.hubspot.pega_mql_yesterday
        on myfirstdatabase.hubspot.hubspot_mql_yesterday.id = myfirstdatabase.hubspot.pega_mql_yesterday.hubspotcontactid
    where myfirstdatabase.hubspot.hubspot_mql_yesterday.id is null or myfirstdatabase.hubspot.pega_mql_yesterday.hubspotcontactid is null;

-- task 4: suspend the warehouse after the chain of tasks 
create or replace task suspendwarehouse3
    warehouse = pc_fivetran_wh
    after create_hubspot_pega_diff_yesterday_table
  as
    alter warehouse compute_wh suspend;
```

When creating the tasks they execute successfully.

When I run the show tasks command:

```
show tasks in pc_fivetran_db.hubspot;
```

This is what I get.
[image]

I appreciate any help or advice on how to fix this error.

Comment: Are the other tasks dependent on the first one (root task as mentioned in the error)?  You may have to suspend the root task in order to alter the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your child tasks named `create_pega_mql_yesterday_table` and `create_hubspot_pega_diff_yesterday_table` are running DDL statements.

Per the Snowflake Tasks [documentation](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-task.html#optional-parameters) for the AFTER parameter, you'll likely need to suspend the root task before you can run these, or use an equivalent non-DDL statement:

> Executing DDL commands on any task in a tree of tasks requires that the root task is suspended. If the root task is currently resumed, then the command returns a user error.

Comment: how can you make the root task resume after it suspends? Do you have to manually resume it?

Answer (score 2):

In snowflake you cannot resume the parent task before child tasks. Always resume tasks before parent task. Resuming child tasks before parent task does not cause any issues because they are dependent on its parent.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this one. Especially when I resume next child task, I get error

> Unable to update graph with root task <root_task> since that root task is not suspended.

As error says, I've to suspend root_task first and resume next child task. But, by doing to, the child task never gets executed. What I found instead was that you can enable all tasks the same time using following system function;

```
SELECT system$task_dependents_enable('<root_task_name>');
```